# Report Raspberry Pi 3 bluetooth version via terminal

Tags: bluetooth

I want to verify my raspberry's Bluetooth module version.

Is there a command through terminal that returns the Bluetooth version?

According to the RPI's CYW43438 communication chip's datasheet the Bluetooth module version is 4.1. Is there any chance that the version can be updated from 4.1 to 4.2 through firmware update or it can only be updated through hardware?

Comment: Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design.

Answer (score 1):

To check the version of the Bluetooth spec of your Raspberry Pi device, turn on Bluetooth and issue the following command in the Terminal:

```
hciconfig -a
```

You should get an output including one line that looks like

```
HCI Version: 0x[X]
```

Where [X] is a number indicating the spec version. According to [the official Bluetooth specification page](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/host-controller-interface), the numbers are:

`6`: 4.0
`7`: 4.1
`8`: 4.2